# Windows Store Notification in Windows Form Application

Tags: winforms, notifications, windows-store-apps

Is it possible to send a Windows Store Notification using Windows Forms? If so, is there any available documentation for this I could read through?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about sending a Toast notification (the rectangular popup in the corner of the screen) then this can be done from a desktop app like your WinForms app. See [Quickstart: Sending a toast notification from the desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh802768.aspx) and the [Sending toast notifications from desktop apps sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=242463)

Answer (score -1):

From your question, I understand that you require Message to be thrown in the style of Windows Store Apps.  However this is not possible AFAIK - You can design a usercontrol to show Windows Store kinda notification from inside Win Forms application.